# Duplicity error

Tags: duplicity

I had to reinstall Ubuntu due to some driver problems. After reinstalling, I tried recovering all my data from my backup, but I kept on getting the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a little bit more explanation, who did you get backup, who are you trying to restore it, what is the version of your Ubuntu. By the way you can create a separate home partition, then after reinstalling your data are already there.

Comment: This is a generic Python error. I can't find any reference to Duplicity errors with this error message, so I would suggest you report it as a bug. Go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that helped. The problem was that I was trying to restore from an exfat formatted drive. Once I copied everything to my ext4 hard drive, it worked just fine.